# How add console.log process.memoryUsage().rss in the node_modules/next/build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, node-modules

I would like to display the amount of memory used while building an application,
in which file and where should it add: `console.log('Memus: ' + Math.round(process.memoryUsage().rss / 1024 / 1024) + ' KB');`